# Rights required to query command line on Win32_Process of windows service running under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM?

Tags: wmi, win32-process

I have a sample application which fires WMI Query on Win32_Process to read the commandline of a process running as a service. When the application is run as administrator it succeeds and return actual commandline of service process. But when I run the application under local user which is given a local admin rights, application does not return any error but commandline value (return by IWbemClassObject::Get()) is empty. Service is running under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Apart from Local Admin what other rights should be given to local user to fetch the commandline successfully?

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

In Vista+ with UAC enabled, an admin user does not run with all admin rights enabled by default, so running a program as an admin user does not guarantee it runs with full admin rights, like it used to in XP.  The program must be run in an elevated state in order to get full admin rights.

Reading the command-line of another process requires the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege.  If the user that is running your app is allowed that privilege, your app can use [`AdjustTokenPrivilege()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) to enable it before then querying the server process information.

[Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619.aspx)